# Set an object with Twig into a template thats imported via another template?

Tags: twig

Im including a link.twig into block.twig, and block.twig into page.twig. in my set options is there a way I can change the link objects name to something like heroLink?

I need to set options within page.twig. link.twig is included into other templates so I dont want to change it (eg changing link.url to heroLink.url).

In my page:

```
{% set options = {
    title: 'my title',
    link: {
      text: 'Search',
      url: "www.google.com"
    }
}
%}
{% include "block.twig" with options %}
```

In block.twig:

```
<div class="something">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <div class="hero">
    {% include "link.twig" with {'style': 'primary'} %}
    </div>
</div>
```

In link.twig:

```
<a href="{{ link.url }}" class="link-class-{ style }}">{{ link.text }}</a>
```

The reason for this is that block.twig actually has other links. link.twig may be imported multiple times. As the mock object needs to be created in page.twig something like heroLink makes a lot more sense in this context.

Comment: `{% include "link.twig" with {'style': 'primary', 'heroLink': link, } %}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my page:

```
  {% set options = {
      action: {
        text: 'Action',
        url: "action.com"
      }
  }
  %}
  {% include "component.twig" with options %}
```

In component.twig:

```
{% import "link.twig" as mainLink %}

{{ mainLink.link(action.url, action.text) }}
```

In link.twig

```
    {% macro link(url, text) %}
      <a href="{{ url }}">{{ text }}</a>
    {% endmacro %}
```